# How can I set OutlinedTextField content to vertically center in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

[image]

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun OutlinedTextField(
    value: String,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    readOnly: Boolean = false,
    textStyle: TextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current,
    placeholder: String? = null,
    label: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    leadingIcon: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    trailingIcon: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = outlinedTextFieldPadding(
        start = 11.dp,
        end = 11.dp,
        top = 8.dp,
        bottom = 8.dp
    ),
    isError: Boolean = false,
    visualTransformation: VisualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
    keyboardOptions: KeyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default,
    keyboardActions: KeyboardActions = KeyboardActions(),
    singleLine: Boolean = false,
    maxLength: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE,
    maxLines: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE,
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
    shape: Shape = RectangleShape,
    colors: androidx.compose.material.TextFieldColors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
        backgroundColor = if (enabled) Color.White else Color.Gray015,
        focusedBorderColor = Color.NeonYellow10,
        unfocusedBorderColor = Color.Gray014,
        disabledBorderColor = Color.Transparent,
        placeholderColor = Color.Gray04
    )
) {
    // If color is not provided via the text style, use content color as a default
    val textColor = textStyle.color.takeOrElse {
        colors.textColor(enabled).value
    }
    val mergedTextStyle = textStyle.merge(TextStyle(color = textColor))

    BasicTextField(
        value = value,
        modifier = if (label != null) {
            modifier
                // Merge semantics at the beginning of the modifier chain to ensure padding is
                // considered part of the text field.
                .semantics(mergeDescendants = true) {}
                .padding(top = 8.dp)
        } else {
            modifier
        }
            .background(colors.backgroundColor(enabled).value, shape)
            .padding(vertical = contentPadding.calculateTopPadding())
            .defaultMinSize(
                minWidth = 120.dp,
                minHeight = 24.dp
            ),
        onValueChange = {
            if (it.length <= maxLength) {
                val text = if (maxLines == 1 || singleLine) {
                    it.replace("\n", "")
                } else {
                    it
                }
                onValueChange(text)
            }
        },
        enabled = enabled,
        readOnly = readOnly,
        textStyle = mergedTextStyle,
        cursorBrush = SolidColor(colors.cursorColor(isError).value),
        visualTransformation = visualTransformation,
        keyboardOptions = keyboardOptions,
        keyboardActions = keyboardActions,
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        singleLine = singleLine,
        maxLines = maxLines,
        decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
            TextFieldDefaults.OutlinedTextFieldDecorationBox(
                value = value,
                visualTransformation = visualTransformation,
                innerTextField = innerTextField,
                placeholder = {
                    if (placeholder != null) {
                        Text(
                            text = placeholder,
                            fontSize = 10.sp,
                            lineHeight = 12.sp,
                            color = colors.placeholderColor(enabled).value,
                        )
                    }
                },
                label = label,
                leadingIcon = leadingIcon,
                trailingIcon = trailingIcon,
                singleLine = singleLine,
                enabled = enabled,
                isError = isError,
                interactionSource = interactionSource,
                colors = colors,
                contentPadding = contentPadding,
                border = {
                    TextFieldDefaults.BorderBox(
                        enabled,
                        isError,
                        interactionSource,
                        colors,
                        shape
                    )
                }
            )
        }
    )
}
```

I'd like to make

```
outlinedTextFieldPadding(
        start = 11.dp,
        end = 11.dp,
        top = 8.dp,
        bottom = 8.dp
    )
```

to

```
outlinedTextFieldPadding(
        start = 11.dp,
        end = 11.dp,
        top = 0.dp,
        bottom = 0.dp
    ),
```

And then, center vertically so that I don't need the vertical padding and it always be vertically center which is no need to set vertical padding.

How can I solve this issue?

I tried with

```
TextFieldDefaults.OutlinedTextFieldDecorationBox()
```

to

```
Column(
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
){
    TextFieldDefaults.OutlinedTextFieldDecorationBox()
}
```

But this gives different look to the OutlinedTextFieldDecorationBox.

Comment: This is a common issue. I have to set the max lines to two then set gravity to vertical. It places it in the correct way. Try that and see if that helps.

Comment: @CampNerd I don't get it. Can you give me some snippet?

Answer (score -1):

To set the content of an OutlinedTextField to be vertically centered in Jetpack Compose, you could use the `Modifier.align` modifier with the `Alignment.CenterVertically` parameter. Here's an example:

```kotlin
OutlinedTextField(
    value = textState.value,
    onValueChange = { newText -> textState.value = newText },
    label = { Text("Enter Text") },
    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
)
```

In this example, the `OutlinedTextField` is wrapped in a `Modifier.align` modifier. The `Alignment.CenterVertically` parameter specifies that the content of the `OutlinedTextField` should be centered vertically within the available space.

You can adjust the vertical alignment by using other `Alignment` parameters such as `Top`, `Bottom`, etc.

Hope this helps as an example.